# How to fetch specific fields in Mongo DB only values without keys?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My data set is following:

```
{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-k9Uoo74Q3WcdmU", "event_data" : "{\"data\":\"helo\"}", "event_name" : "onOemPushAlert", "timestamp_start" : 1452678481433, "timestamp_end" : 1452678481433, "sender" : "USR-ADMIN", "status" : "pending", "query" : { "user" : { "and" : [ { "email" : { "eq" : "" } } ] } }, "updated_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T09:48:01.459Z"), "created_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T09:48:01.459Z") }

{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-yAKmrbzs2JeaUY", "event_data" : "{\"data\":\"ji\"}", "event_name" : "onOemPushAlert", "timestamp_start" : 1452681060159, "timestamp_end" : 1452681060159, "sender" : "USR-ADMIN", "status" : "pending", "query" : { "user" : { "@@@and@@@" : [ { "email" : { "eq" : "" } } ] } }, "updated_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T10:31:00.223Z"), "created_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T10:31:00.223Z") }

{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-0NeCstt2eJchDZ", "event_data" : "{\"data\":\"hyg\"}", "event_name" : "onOemPushAlert", "timestamp_start" : 1452681073882, "timestamp_end" : 1452681073882, "sender" : "USR-ADMIN", "status" : "pending", "query" : { "user" : { "@@@and@@@" : [ { "email" : { "eq" : "" } } ] } }, "updated_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T10:31:13.897Z"), "created_on" : ISODate("2016-01-13T10:31:13.897Z") }
```

and i am running following query

```
db.eventqueries.find({},{_id:1})
```

but it give me

```
{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-k9Uoo74Q3WcdmU" }
{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-yAKmrbzs2JeaUY" }
{ "_id" : "EVNQUERY-0NeCstt2eJchDZ" }
```

but what i want is

```
["EVNQUERY-k9Uoo74Q3WcdmU", "EVNQUERY-yAKmrbzs2JeaUY", "EVNQUERY-0NeCstt2eJchDZ"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform a **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** query against the `_id` field on the collection:

```
db.eventqueries.distinct("_id")
```

In the node.js driver run the **[`distinct()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct)** command which would have a callback with the results:

```
collection.distinct("_id", function(err, docs) {
    if (err) { /* handle error */ };
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to achieve what you want. You can try this out

```
db.eventqueries.aggregate([
   {
       $group : {
           keys : { $push : "_id" }
       }
   }
])
```